# Is there a faster way to identify if a mobile application is present?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, mobile-browser

```
document.location = "fb://";
```

I use the above code to launch my facebook application in Firefox browser in my Android mobile device. But it takes a longer time to sense if the application is present. Is there a f
aster way to check if a mobile application is present from the firefox mobile web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Detect Mobile Browsers. It's an Open Source mobile detection library that is available in a range of languages.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Not 100% sure about all the languages though I gather they are the same, the Javascript versions return a boolean value so it's easy to work with.